# Unity in portrait mode on Dell inspiron 13 7000 w/ i7

Tags: unity, inspiron

Does Unity (from 14.10 or 15.04) work well in portrait mode on the latest Dell Inspiron 13 2-in-1?
I know of problems w/ touchpad and touchscreen, which can be solved, but I would like to get feedback on the usability of the device in "reading mode" (which I do a lot) before considering buying it.

What is the support of PDF readers?

Has someone had a nice experience with Ubuntu on another convertible notebook? (e.g Lenovo Yoga)